# How to connect Apache Kafka with Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to store data from Kafka into a bucket s3 using Kafka Connect. I had already a Kafka's topic running and I had a bucket s3 created. My topic has data on Protobuffer, I tried with https://github.com/qubole/streamx and I obtained the next error:

```
 [2018-10-04 13:35:46,512] INFO Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group connect-s3-sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:280)
 [2018-10-04 13:35:46,512] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-s3-sink (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:326)
 [2018-10-04 13:35:46,645] INFO Successfully joined group connect-s3-sink with generation 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:434)
 [2018-10-04 13:35:46,692] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [ssp.impressions-11, ssp.impressions-10, ssp.impressions-7, ssp.impressions-6, ssp.impressions-9, ssp.impressions-8, ssp.impressions-3, ssp.impressions-2, ssp.impressions-5, ssp.impressions-4, ssp.impressions-1, ssp.impressions-0] for Group connect-s3-sink(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:219)
 [2018-10-04 13:35:47,193] ERROR Task s3-sink-0 threw an uncaught an unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:142)
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.close(HdfsSinkTask.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.closePartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2018-10-04 13:35:47,194] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:143)
[2018-10-04 13:35:51,235] INFO Reflections took 6844 ms to scan 259 urls, producing 13517 keys and 95788 values (org.reflections.Reflections:229)
```

I did the next steps:

1. I cloned the repository.
2. `mvn DskipTests package`
3. `nano config/connect-standalone.properties`

   ```
   bootstrap.servers=ip-myip.ec2.internal:9092
   key.converter=com.qubole.streamx.ByteArrayConverter
   value.converter=com.qubole.streamx.ByteArrayConverter
   ```
4. `nano config/quickstart-s3.properties`

   ```
   name=s3-sink 
   connector.class=com.qubole.streamx.s3.S3SinkConnector
   format.class=com.qubole.streamx.SourceFormat tasks.max=1
   topics=ssp.impressions
   flush.size=3
   s3.url=s3://myaccess_key:mysecret_key@mybucket/demo
   ```
5. `connect-standalone /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties quickstart-s3.properties`

I would like to know if that I did is okay or another way to keep data into S3 from Kafka.

Comment: What tutorial did you find? Any new Kafka consumer can be configured to read from beginning offset for existing data

Comment: You should indicate in your question text if you fundamentally reword it to ask a different question. My answer stands to your original question of "how to connect to Apache Kafka to S3".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Kafka Connect to do this integration, with the Kafka Connect S3 connector.

[Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) is part of Apache Kafka, and the [S3 connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html) is an open-source connector available either [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

For general information and examples of Kafka Connect, this series of articles might help:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and wrote the above blog articles.*

---

**April 2020**: I have recorded a video showing how to use the S3 sink: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-s3-video

Comment: I want to use Kafka Connect, but I have the data on Protobuffer, that can be a problem? 

key.converter=
value.converter=
key.converter.schemas.enable=
value.converter.schemas.enable=
internal.key.converter=
internal.value.converter=
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=

Comment: Yes there is an open-source protobuf converter for Kafka Connect that you can use: https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter/

Comment: I had many questions. Can I connect to my Kafka Cluster from an other Kafka instance and run in a standalone way my Kafka Connector s3? What means this error "ERROR Task s3-sink-0 threw an uncaught an unrecoverable exception"? If you can resume the steps to connect to Kafka and keep on s3 from another Kafka instance, how will you do?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to write a consumer with log rotation and then corn files to S3 .